# Block scroll UIViewCollection before stop scrolling

Tags: ios, swift

I have class UIViewCollection. I need will block UIViewCollection and unlock after terminating scroll animation UIViewCollection. This method work good but while when i touch to screen it's not complete scrolling

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Correct your description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CollectionView inherits from UIScrollView you can set the property 
collectionView.isScrollEnabled to true or false as you see fit, however in the code you shared I see that you want to scroll to each item in your collection like it was pages in a book, right? to achieve that there is another property called paging, and you can set it to true or false as well, I believe it would be something like collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true or false as you wish, hope this helps